# How do I find the source of netlink operations in linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I have unexplained changes to my network interfaces. Something is removing the IP addresses I attach manually. I can see it when I do `ip -d monitor`:

```
[…]
Deleted local 192.168.111.3 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.111.3
[…]
```

I see there's a whole bunch of processes with netlink sockets (`wc -l /proc/net/netlink`). Some of which are systemd, so I'm suspecting something is trying to be "smart" by "claiming ownership" of the network interface, deleting all its settings to set its own. Whatever it is I want to stop it doing that, but I need to find it first.

I'm suspecting systemd, which does have a few `netlink` sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `pid` in netlink messages that `ip monitor` reads, while documented to mean "port ID" is actually the process ID.

There'll be some garbage to go through manually, but the pid can be seen if doing:

`strace -erecvmsg ip monitor dev eth0 > /dev/null`

For someone in the future who wants to make a dedicated tool for this, I'd first recommend adding showing the the PID to the existing `ip` tool. If not, then start by reading `netlink(7)` and `rtnetlink(7)` manpages.

Comment: No, the "nl_pid" is still the "port ID" and not a PID. Based on older documentation there is the suggestion to allocate a unique port ID by simply using the PID, but this is unusable as soon as an application needs to open multiple AF_NETLINK sockets simultaneously. In fact, a quick `cat /proc/net/netlink` or `ss -f netlink` shows non-PID values for some port IDs.